# Select element by style and ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select an element by id and a style?

```
var iframe=document.getElementById('contframe[style*="block"]');
```

Something such as the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, You can't get element like that, But you can do this.

**First:** Get the element with id

```
const element = document.querySelector('#contframe');
or
var element = document.getElementById('contframe');
```

**Second:** check whether it has `display: block`

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).display == 'block';
```

**Note:** 
`getComputedStyle` is not supported in IE ([More details here](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle))

Comment: is there a way for getComputedStyle to run through an array of elements?

Comment: Just ran a for loop and it worked, thank you very much.